# Java Spring Boot Unit Test Service State not Refreshing for each Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Java Spring Boot. Please does anyone know why my *service*'s state is not refreshing before each unit test?

I've been trying to fix this for a whole day if not more and am yet to find out why. I thought the @BeforeEach would refresh the service again before each unit test, but this is not working.

*test1* changes the state of *service* and passes the assertion but the state of *service* is carried into *test2*, which is the issue. This therefore makes *test2* fail

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
class BeachResortServiceApplicationTests {

        private PersonDataAccessService service;

        @BeforeEach
        void init() {
            service = new PersonDataAccessService();
        }

        @Test
        void test1() {
            System.out.println("Test1");

            UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
            Person bob = new Person(id, "Bob");

            service.insertPerson(bob);

            assert(service.getPersonById(id).equals(bob));
        }

        @Test
        void test2() {
            System.out.println("Test2");
            System.out.println(service.getAllPersons());

            //this assertion fails because service still has Bob in it but service should have been cleared
            //according to the @BeforeEach method.
            assertThat(service.getAllPersons()).hasSize(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think it might be because still test are executing on `junit-4`, so try using `@Before` instead of `@BeforEach`

Comment: The service instance will be new for each test. How are you persisting the Person data ?

Comment: @Deadpool It's not allowing me to use `@Before` for some reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: @R.G thanks for suggesting that. So I was storing the person data in a static list called DB just to fake that data. Inserting adds to the list, etc. So I removed the static keyword and it now passes the test, which makes sense. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: @AliHejazi , storing data to a static object is not the correct approach. I hope you understand that a static object will be common to all  the instances of that class ( here `PersonDataAccessService`) and hence the issue although `@BeforeEach` worked as expected. If this is a unit test , you can always mock the repository layer to unit test the service method logic.

Comment: @R.G yes that makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: This is not the correct way of writing a test case which has Spring Framework context loaded.

Comment: @IanLim if possible could you please explain what you mean? Or maybe link to a tutorial? I am new to Spring so I would love to learn the correct way of doing so.